# SFML window closes with a segmentation fault

Tags: c++, pointers, sfml

Working on implementing a basic state stack and have made a basic menu. I'm accessing the menu through a shared pointer. The window loads up correctly but when I go to draw an object (from a different class that has a copy of the shared pointer as an attribute) nothing happens. The window remains blank (or rather see-through) [example here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11nIhvJ3OxhfUrsdFfRsEtg46LFv3z8jr/view?usp=sharing), though does not freeze (the window can still be moved around) until it's closed, where the program stops with a seg fault on the line where the class attempts to draw an object.

```
void Menu::draw() {
    // Draw text objects
    game->window->draw(title);
    game->window->draw(play);
    game->window->draw(settings);
}
```

> `game` is a pointer to the game manager class (which handles the state stack) and it has a smart pointer to a `window` as one of its attributes

---

I've established that all the relevent functions (init, update and draw) are running and checked that the window object is not destroyed but can't seem to find any reason for this.

I'm developing the program on GitHub [here](https://github.com/danielg0/open-tms/tree/0.1-dev) and would be grateful for any input as to why the program isn't functioning.

**EDIT:** The window wasn't appearing because I wasn't calling the windows draw function. However the program still fails with a seg fault when the window is closed on the game manager draw function:

```
// Run draw function for the top state
void gameManager::draw() {
    // Clear window
    window->clear(sf::Color::Black);

    // Call the draw function of the class atop the stack
    stateStack.top()->draw();

    // Display the changes to the window
    window->display();
}
```

> The `window` is a smart pointer to a RenderWindow object and the `stateStack.top()->draw();` returns the draw function (see above for example) for the state currently running

Comment: Do you call `window.display()` in your code?

Comment: (Facepalm) Nope. I knew there was a good chance it'd be something obvious. Despite this though, it still quits with a seg fault when the window is closed.

Comment: please send us the piece of code you use for rendering (as small as possible)

Comment: Have edited the question to include a sample the draw function

Comment: Hi again! I think you can't (shouldn't) call `clear` nor `draw` methods when your window is closed.

Comment: Yes, I hadn't spotted that, thanks for the help. Will have to reorganise the main loop - perhaps add a return value.